# How Return to VFPage from standard Cancel button

Tags: apex

I have a button on my vfpage that opens New Account Standard page.
After Save or cancel its redirecting to home tab but I want to redirect to my vf page.
How can I set retUrl of my VF Page in the Pagereference. Or if there is another way?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the 'retURL' parameter.

For example:

```
'/001/e?retURL=%2Fapex%2FMyVFPage%2F'
```

which will return the user to /apex/MyVFPage/